# How to create a char pointer in C++ that points to a concatenation of integers and commas?

Tags: c++

Sorry if the terms are not right, just starting in C++ here... I have the following variables whose values can be 1 or 0 depending on another script result:

```
int number1, number2;
```

I need to format a variable as "X,Y" ending with a new line, so I did:

```
char c_number1 = '0' + number1; //going from int to char
char c_number2 = '0' + number2;
char comma = ',';
char new_line = '\n';
char concat_result[100] = {c_number1 + comma + c_number2 + new_line};
```

**Here I don't get the expected result "X,Y" but a letter.**

After that, I would need a pointer to that char variable, so I wrote:

```
const char *pointer_result = concat_result;
```

Not sure this is correct either.

Any guidance by any chance here?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `char` and arrays of `char` rather than using `std::string`? `std::string` would make this code a lot easier to write, and would be a lot less confusing for beginners

Comment: `std::stringstream ss; ss << number1 << "," << number2 << "\n"; std::string s = ss.str();`

Comment: I need to use chars as I'm using a library function down the road that takes a const char* as input.

Comment: @garys After you create the `std::string` with the desired text, you can use `std::string::c_str()` to get a `const char*` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways to handle this:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::stream result = std::to_string(number1) + "," + std::to_string(number2) + "\n";
const char *pointer_result = result.c_str();
```

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << number1 << ',' << number2 << '\n';
std::string result = oss.str();
const char *pointer_result = result.c_str();
```

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

char result[5];
std::sprintf(result, "%d,%d\n", number1, number2);
const char *pointer_result = result;
```

Comment: I didn't know about `c_str()`, that's what I needed!

Comment: NB: I get the error `stream is not a member of std` when trying the first option. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to store each characters to separate elements of the array.

To archive that, use `,` instead of `+` to separate the elements.

```
char concat_result[100] = {c_number1, comma, c_number2, new_line};
```

This will initialize the first 4 elements with the specified characters and the other elements with zero.

Then you can use

```
const char *pointer_result = concat_result;
```

because most of arrays in expressions are converted to a pointer to the first element and assigning pointers without `const` to pointers having compatible types with `const` is allowed.

Comment: A string would be preferable.

Comment: Yes indeed, "," instead of "+" would be a good start :) Am I supposed to end a char array with '\0', '\r', '\n' or just nothing to indicate the end of the assignment?

Comment: You have enough elements in the array, so zero is automatically inserted after last explicit element and you need not to explicitly write `'\0'`. (You can write that for readability and avoiding risk of changing the number of elements to insufflcient value later)